# Return or display non-duplicate rows from insert statement

Tags: postgresql

I am inserting multiple rows of data into a table using a query similar to the following:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, col1, col2)
VALUES (123, 'some_value', 'some_other_value')
ON CONFLICT (id, col1, col2) DO NOTHING
```

where a composite key of id,col1 and col2 (example specific), is used to prevent duplicates from being inserted into the table. Is there a quick way to return or display the non-duplicate rows that were inserted into the table?

Comment: [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html): *The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted (or updated, if an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause was used).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `RETURNING` clause, like @adrian-klaver suggested:

```
INSERT INTO foo(a, b)
VALUES (1, 'test'), (2, 'test2'), (1, 'not_returned')
ON CONFLICT (a) DO NOTHING
RETURNING *;
```

This will return the inserted values the same way as if you queried them using `SELECT *`.